# Unity Editor crashes in play with mfperfhelper.dll Access Violation

Tags: c#, .net, windows, unity-game-engine, crash

Recently my Unity Editor (probably the build too, didn't test it yet) crashes randomly while playing - sometimes immediately, sometimes after 5 Minutes, sometimes never.

The error.log begins with

```
Unity Editor by Unity Technologies [version: Unity 2018.2.16f1_39a4ac3d51f6]

mfperfhelper.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module mfperfhelper.dll at 0033:0ec318cc.

Error occurred at 2018-11-18_135334.
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe, run by user.
```

---

Any ideas what this is about and why this occurs randomly without any visible pattern?

Looking forward to a solution and best regards,
thelaumix

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an error within that library (mfperfhelper) or a misuse of it by Unity itself. Time to upgrade Unity or revert back to an older version :)

If that won't fix the problem, you'd need to research where this library comes from. If it's not shipped with Unity, you might need to manually install a new version of the library.